# How to dynamic continues increase the number of html table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a html table which data is retrieved from database after that i can add new row to enter the data but the nummbering wont continues of last number, my question is how to increasing the numbering of the table, please see the pictere :https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6CbE.jpg

**This is my javascript when the button + clicked the new row will append to the table**

```
$('#btn_add_dependents').click(function(){
var i = 0;
i +=1;
$('#tbl_dependents_info').append(
'<tr class="odd"><td style="margin-left:10px;text-align:center;" class="no"></td> '
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_name' + i + '" name="dependents_name[]" type="text" size="15" ></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><select  id="dependents_gender'+ i + '" name="dependents_gender[]">'
+'<option value="1">Male</option>'
+'<option value="2">Female</option></select></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><select  id="dependents_relationship'+ i + '" name="dependents_relationship[]">'+ relationship +'</select></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_occupation' + i     + '" name="dependents_occupation[]" type="text" size="15" ></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_dob' + i + '" name="dependents_dob[]" type="date" ></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_remark' + i + '" name="dependents_remark[]" type="text" size="20" ></td>'
+'<td style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/subtract.png" style="height:20px;" id="del" ></td>'
+'</tr>');
updateRowOrder();
return false;
 });

  function updateRowOrder() {
    $('td.no').each(function (i) { 
       $(this).text(i + 1);
    });

}

$( document ).on( "click", "#del", function() {
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
 updateRowOrder();
});
 });
```

**This is function of retrieved the data from database and put in html table**

```
$sql="SELECT name,gender,cust_dependent.relationship as relationship_id,relationship.relationship,occupation,d_o_b,remark
FROM cust_dependent 
INNER JOIN relationship ON relationship.id = cust_dependent.relationship
WHERE cust_id = $customer_id AND createdby = $user_id "; 
$query=$db->query($sql);
while ($row=$db->fetch_assoc($query)){
    $i++;
    $name=$row['name'];
    $gender=$row['gender'];
    $relationship_id = $row['relationship_id'];
    $relationship=$row['relationship'];
    $occupation=$row['occupation'];
    $d_o_b=$row['d_o_b'];
    $remark=$row['remark'];
    $relationship=$slctrl->getSelectRelationship($relationship_id);
    echo<<<EOF
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">$i</td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_name$i" name="dependents_name[]" type="text" size="15" value="$name"></td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><select id="dependents_gender$i" name="dependents_gender[]">
                                        <option value="1" $male>Male</option>
                                        <option value="2" $female>Female</option></select></td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><select  id="dependents_relationship$i" name="dependents_relationship[]">$relationship</select></td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_occupation$i" name="dependents_occupation[]" type="text" size="15" value="$occupation" ></td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_dob$i" name="dependents_dob[]" type="date" value="$d_o_b"></td>
    <td class="odd" style="text-align:center;"><input id="dependents_remark$i" name="dependents_remark[]" type="text" size="20"value="$remark" ></td>
```

```
    EOF;}}
```

**I can add the row now but the numbering is wrong its will start as 1, how to let it became continue number of last row? 
ps:last row data is retrived from database.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve the value(value here indicates number of rows present in your html table). When you retrieve the rows from database , then save the count in some variable , say **$count**. Set this **$count** variable in html input field(make it hidden) as

```
< input type="hidden" id="table-count" value="$count">
```

And in jquery
while *adding* row , do

```
$currentRowNo = parseInt($('#table-count').val())++; //get value

$('#table-count').val($currentRowNo) // update value

while deletion, simply subtract the value

$currentRowNo = parseInt($('#table-count').val())--; //get value

$('#table-count').val($currentRowNo) // update value
```

Comment: Hi,thanks your reply, I had tried its work but I still meet a problem, please see the picture
http://imgur.com/1Z1ISkI,YrQF1Se#1
this is I clicked one time + button, the number is correct
http://imgur.com/1Z1ISkI,YrQF1Se#0
this is I clicked second time + button, the 3 will became 4 too,
this is my code after I use your code
`function updateRowOrder() {
    var currentRowNo = parseInt($('#table_count').val());
    currentRowNo +=1;
      $('td.no').each(function () { 
    $(this).text(currentRowNo);
      });
    $('#table_count').val(currentRowNo);
        }`

Comment: And I am sorry that I am newbie on Jqeury but I think the problem at 
`$('td.no').each(function () { 
    $(this).text(currentRowNo);

  });`

Comment: look... on ADD click, set td.no value when you are dynamically adding row in table using this function  "$('#tbl_dependents_info').append( " ... no need to call updateRowOrder() ... when you are deleting a row , you need to reorder the whole table ... for this call updaterowOrder() and update its code with " var i = 1;
  $('td.no').each(function () { 
    $(this).text(i);
    i++;

  });    "

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function updateRowOrder() {
  var i = 1;
  $('td.no').each(function () { 
    $(this).text(i);
    i++;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your index value on click of **+** button from the last index value you got from database.

You can preserve the last index value you got from database in a hidden field and also update this value on every click on **+** button.